# Why does the MacMenuBarExtra label only work for sf symbol images and text?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using a MacMenuBarExtra for my macOS app, however, I can't seem to make any view that's not a sf symbol image or text render properly. Here is the code I am using in my app file and if you run it, you'll see that no icon shows in the menu bar. I want to create a dynamic icon which will show up there, does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
MenuBarExtra {
    ContentView()
} label: {
    Circle().foregroundColor(.green)       
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
```

Comment: At least for Text and Image("customized name") is ok. I am not sure why certain shape get ignored.

Comment: Doesn't work for custom images, only sf symbols seem to work.